# Version Tracking local jars in Nexus

Tags: java, maven, nexus

How can i use nexus to assign version numbers for my local jars.. Can we do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Version numbering is specified in your POM.

Comment: ... your pom.xml used by maven. When you `deploy` or `release` using maven, the version information is attatched to the jar's name and meta data.

Comment: Aren't you using mvn release:prepare and mvn release:perform ? Neither 1.0-SNAPSHOT ?

Answer (score 0):

The ivy module has a [buildnumber](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/buildnumber.html) task that caculates based on what was previously published to Nexus.